# How can I diagnose why my oil burner is not coming on?

Tags: furnace

I have a Buderus oil furnace with a Riello burner and Hydrostat controller and it does not appear to be coming on when it should. For example, right now the controller has the green dot lit, which means there is a call for heat, but the furnace is not firing. Hydrostat says the temperature of the furnace is 67 which the ambient temperature of the basement. Some of the thermostats in the house are below temp. I followed the burner-not-coming-on troubleshoot flow chart in the Hydrostat guide as follows:

```
Does the display read "Pur"? NO
Is the Green LED (TEMP ACTIVE) on? YES
Is the Red LED (LOW WATER) on? NO
Is the Yellow LED (HI TEMP) on? NO
Is the Yellow LED (TARGET) on? NO
Is the Thermostat (T-T) calling for heat? YES
Is there 120 VAC between B1 and B2? YES
```

So, the guide says "HydroStat is supplying 120 VAC to the burner circuit. Recheck wiring and operation of burner and other limit controls."

So, something is wrong with the burner maybe? There is oil in the furnace.

Yesterday, I pushed the reset button and the furnace came on and ran, but I don't want to keep doing that.

Comment: Sounds like you had a hard lockout. That's usually caused by actual operating conditions or a bad sensor. I dk how to diagnose it, so that's why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Might be an ignition problem. Might be a flame sensor problem. Might be something else. IMHO it's "time to call a licensed oiler burner service technician" and get it sorted. Most insurance requires an annual servicing anyway...

Comment: "Recheck wiring and operation of burner and other limit controls." and what are the results of this recheck?